# Import excel (csv) data into R conducting bioinformatics task

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I'm a new who is exploring bioinformatics via R. Right now I've encounter a trouble, where I imported my data in excel into R through changing it into csv format and using read.csv command, as you see in the pic there are 37 variables (column) where first column is supposed to be considered as fixed factor. And I would like to match it with another matirx which has only 36 variables in the downstream processing, what should I do to reduce variable numbers by fixing first column?

[image]

Many thanks in advance.

---

sure, I added str() properties of my data here.

[image]

Comment: can you show the `str(yourdata)`

Comment: you want to create a new data frame with 104573 observations and 35+36 other columns right.. basically join according to the first column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, what you are looking for is setting the "Gene" column as metadata, indicating what gene those values in every row correspond to. You can try then to delete the word "Gene" in the Excel file because when you import it with the `read.csv()` function, the argument `row.names = TRUE` is set as default when "there is a header and the first row contains one fewer field than the number of columns".

You can find more information about this function using `?read.csv`